# How do I change the batteries in my wireless mouse?

Tags: mouse

How do I change the batteries in my Logitech M215 wireless mouse? I have lost the instructions and it has a blinking red light.

Comment: http://support.logitech.com/en_nz/product/wireless-mouse-m215

Comment: http://support.logitech.com/en_nz/article/14454?product=a0qi00000069uePAAQ

Comment: @Moses nice effort, but unfortunately those links are useless. The image in the 2nd link doesn't show, and the first one has no downloads.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the links are useless or not, the make and model of the mouse have been mentioned, and with a simple Google search I could easily find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8_krul_HYU

In this youtube video it is shown how you can reach the battery.

The video shows that on the bottom back side of the Logitech M215 there is a 'release' button. When you press it in deeply (don't go crazy with it), the back cover will pop up. You can now lift off the back cover, and the tip of a single battery will be revealed. You should be able to pull the battery out, and place a charged battery back.

Please be advised not all batteries can be recharged. Often if not always, it is written on the battery if you can or cannot recharge it. Do not try to recharge a battery that is not chargeable, in the worst (not too likely) case the battery can light on fire or explode. If a battery is chargeable, also be advised that not all batteries can be charged in the same manner. You battery charger needs to be compatible with the type of battery. Some chargers have a switch on them, so you can select the type of battery you wish to charge.

Of course you can always simply replace the battery with a new one.